# Как узнать latLng точкек B2, D2?

Tags: google-maps-api

Я строю полигон (имеет вид прямоугольника) `AB1C1D1`, и вращаю его на некий угол (см. рисунок приведённый ниже). После я перетаскиваю нижний правый маркер с позиции `С1` до позиции `C2`. В результате я должен получить расширенный полигон`AB2C2D2`, но проблема в том, что я не могу рассчитать широту и долготу точек `B2` и `D2`. Как узнать широту и долготу точкек `B2`, `D2`? [image: Рисунок]

Answer (score 1):

Если вы знаете адреса этих точек, то вы можете использовать **[этот инструмент](https://itouchmap.com/latlong.html)** для получения координат. Также вы можете щелкнуть на избранной точке в картах Гугл. Когда откроется карта, слева будет панель. Закройте эту панель и в адресной строке увидите координаты данной точки. Прилагаю пример для Перми

[image: пример для Перми].

Также вы можете использовать **[этот инструмент](http://www.birdtheme.org/useful/v3tool.html)** с фильтрами для фигур.

Comment: Точки нужно рассчитать и получать при перетаскивании маркера с позиции С1 до позиции С2

Comment: На позиции C2 щелкните на карте Гугл и она вам выдаст адрес этой точки или даже координаты.

Comment: При постоянном перемещении маркера, эти две точки нужно рассчитывать математическим путем.

Comment: Эти точки должны расчитываться математическим путем.